# How can I load an index.html file using Fast API on the localhost?

Tags: html, static, fastapi

I have tried :
`app.mount("", StaticFiles(directory="index.html", html = True), name="index.html")`

as well as :

```
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="/")

app.mount("/", StaticFiles(directory="/"))

@app.get("/")
def serve_home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", context= {"request": request})
```

In both cases I could not import static files using :
`from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles`

It seems `from fastapi import FastAPI` also could not be resolved but that did not stop the program from working before I tried loading the html file,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need code:

```py
# main.py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()
# first 'static' specify route path, second 'static' specify html files directory.
app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='static',html=True))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

After running `main.py`, access by `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/index.html`
the project tree is:

```bash
$ tree app
app
├── main.py
└── static
    └── index.html
```

Reference https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/.

Hope this is useful.